# Facebook application view error

Tags: javascript, api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a problem with my Facebook application, when my colleague and i view the application we see nothing special, but when someone from outside goes to the application he see only a 404 error page.

I have tried to delete the cookies and application from my Facebook account but when i search for the application he will ask again to connect, and this only happend by my colleague and i.

What is the right solution on this problem?

Comment: impossible to know without code etc. is your facebook app pointing to an internal server/local host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope that part is working ok, as Joshua said, we can view the app without problems. But everybody else gets an 404. You can view the app here: https://apps.facebook.com/pronostiekje/

Answer (score 1):

Check you application settings, it should be in sandbox mode, that's why only developers can use the application.